# вывод элементов файла

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая в качестве аргумента принимает имя файла (не указан файл или указан несуществующий — ошибка) и выводит его содержимое на экран.
В добавок, программа может принимать дополнительные агрументы:
«--count» для вывода кол-ва строк в конце сообщения,
«--num» для вывода порядкового номера с пробелом в начале каждой строки,
«--sort» для сортировки строк в алфавитном порядке перед выводом.
Пусть файл text1.txt содержит строки:

Houston

we have

a problem

Вот мой код:

```
sp = text1.txt

if com[2 : ] == "--count":
    for i in range(len):
        print(i, sp[i])
elif com[2 : ] == "--num":
    for i in range(len):
        print(sp[i])
        
else:
    print(sorted(sp))
```

Не понимаю, что делать дальше, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Для аргументов командной строки удобный модуль - `argparse`, почитайте доки попробуйте. Там же как аргумент передавайте название файла (У Вас это первым требованием стоит). Для проверки существования файла используйте модуль `os`. Далее в зависимости от переданных доп параметров прочитайте файл обычным `open`, и выведите содержимое. Попробуйте сами реализовать, что не получится выкладывайте сюда с вопросом.

Comment: ```
import sys


try:
    name = int(sys.argv[3])
    argument = int(sys.argv[2])
    if argument == "--count":

    elif argument == "--num":

    else:

except BaseException:
    print("ERROR")

```  А как реализовать вывод всех строк и нумерование перед ними?